# Magento 2.2.2 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\DefaultBackend\Interceptor::getResource(

Tags: magento2, getresource

**Magento 2.2.2**

I created a Magento 2 shop and I keep getting the mentioned error (full error https://pastebin.com/rfH2R1Aa).

I also cleared the cache, recompiled, redeployed, deleted generated folder.

Nothing helped, the error keeps coming up whenever I try adding a product to the cart and sometimes just randomly.

Any ideas?